# Does String match glob pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, wildcard, glob

I have an array of paths, let's say:

```
/Users/alansouza/workspace/project/src/js/components/chart/Graph.js
```

Also I have an entry in a configuration file with additional attributes for this path in a wildcard(glob) format, as in:

```
{
  '**/*.js': {
    runBabel: true
  }
}
```

**Question**: Is there an easy way to validate if the path matches the wildcard expression?

For example:

```
const matches = Glob.matches(
  '**/*.js',
  '/Users/alansouza/workspace/project/src/js/components/chart/Graph.js'
);

if (matches) {
  //do something
}
```

FYI: I'm using https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Comment: hey, I'm not familiar with 2 asterisks in a row in a glob expression, in your sample what is the difference between `*` and `**`?

Comment: I think I understand your question, I just don't understand what the meaning of 2 stars in a row is in a glob expression

Comment: Your edit doesn' bring a response to the (good) question from @chiliNUT! So, again: what is `**` supposed to mean?

Comment: Sorry again. It means it will match any subdirectories levels in the path. I'm not an expert in the glob pattern myself, so check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532929/two-asterisks-in-file-path

Comment: cool, I just learned something new :). So, my idea would be to convert the glob to a regex, which javascript can then use to validate path names. here's an npm that can do that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-to-regexp

Comment: Yeah i just got to the same conclusion. would you mind posting as an answer so I can accept it? It would be nice if node-glob supported it by default (I will deal this as a feature request in the project itself)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could convert the glob to to a regex with node `glob-to-regex` and then validate path strings against the regex.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-to-regexp

it looks like `node glob` is another option. 
https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

And node has its own glob implementation
https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch

My first thought was to see if `phpjs` had implemented a glob function but it looks like they haven't :( 
http://locutus.io/php/

Comment: well I'm using node-glob myself. but it does not have the "match" support I'm looking for.

Comment: off the tip of my head (haven't tested) it seems like you could do something like replace a single star with `([^./]*)` and double star with `([^/]+/*)+` and just call that the regex

Comment: @AlanSouza also found `minimatch` though it still might have the same limitations as `node-glob` since its by the same guy

Answer (score 9):

As @chiliNUT theorized in a comment, [`minimatch`](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) has this behaviour:

```
minimatch("file.js", "**/*.js") // true/false
minimatch.match(["file1.js", "file2.js"], "**/*.js") // array of matches
```

Comment: Nice! This is a great resolution to my kind of incomplete answer