# Meaning of a double star (**) in a file path

Tags: javascript, path

I was reading [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604767/2275800) about ** in a path, as in this example:

```
src/js/**/*.js
```

I would like to ask if " ** " means "any nested directory" please?!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `src/js/**/*.js` matches all `.js` files below the `src/js/`directory, at any depth, regardless of the sub-directory structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two asterisks in file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532929/two-asterisks-in-file-path)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the \*\* glob character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604656/what-is-the-glob-character)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The double star in this case means *all folders within the current folder*, with the current folder being `src/js`

So in full, *find all files with a .js extension, in all subfolders of src/js*

Answer (score 31):

The double asterisks are placeholders or instructions to the recursive interpreter to go through the files and folders. It is a simple, recursive wildcard while only one asterisk means all without recursion.

`'**/*.js';` All files with the extension .js from here onwards.

`'lib/**/*.js';` All files with the extension .js in the folder lib and its subfolders.

`'js/**';` All files in the folder js and its subfolders.

Comment: thank you. It's crazy Google SEO cannot find a single link when I searched this most general case.

Answer (score 0):

Glob patterns basically serves as a wild card.  ** wildcard is recursive and works as a path element, which matches zero or more path elements. For example, java/**/*.java matches both the java/Main.java and java/com/android/Main.java patterns.