# What double ** do in an import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have cloned [this library](https://github.com/cvdlab/react-planner/blob/master/demo/src/catalog/mycatalog.js) and in this library they are using an import with a double astrix, like this:

```
import * as Areas from './areas/**/planner-element.jsx';
```

Can anyone explain what is this `**` and what it does ?

Comment: It's a globstar

Comment: It depends entirely on what's processing that import. It would be meaningless in a browser per current spec, for instance, but presumably you're using Webpack or Browserify or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two asterisks in file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532929/two-asterisks-in-file-path)

Comment: also duplicate of [Meaning of a double star (**) in a file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547540/meaning-of-a-double-star-in-a-file-path)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am getting this error 
./src/catalog/mycatalog.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './holes/**/planner-element.jsx' in '/Users/syookdeveloper/Syook/syook-tnt-client/src/catalog'

Do I need to install something to use ** ?

Comment: That is a different question, one question at a time please

Answer (score 4):

It's a pattern to identify folders and sub-folders recursively.

For example if they have something like

```
areas/foo/planner-element.jsx
areas/foo/bar/planner-element.jsx
```

It will identify both of them. It's like a more loose notation, so it's not really important where that file is, just that it's somewhere under `areas`

Comment: I wouldn't call it a regex

Comment: @Alexander you are correct, changed the word. It was the first to pop in my mind

Answer (score 1):

`\**\` This pattern is used for recursive folder tree traversal.

Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532929/two-asterisks-in-file-path)

Comment: This needs more explanation, what does recursive folder tree traversal mean?

Answer (score 0):

`./lines/**/planner-element.jsx` translates to the file `planner-element.jsx` in any directory under the lines directory.
A single asterisk translates to any character up the first / (so ./lines/*.jsx will include all jsx files in the lines directory).
A double asterisk translates to any character, which means not only file names but also directories are taken into account (and so ./lines/**/planner-element.jsx will include any file named planner-element.jsx which is in any direrctory underneath the lines directory)

Answer (score -1):

** denotes folder any folder names in the path and also can be mutiple child folders.