# How to evaluate double asterisk (star) in path?

Tags: python-3.x, path, wildcard

Any double asterisk in a path means all [sub-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547540/meaning-of-a-double-star-in-a-file-path).

Now if I have a path like this `a/b/c/**/*.txt` Which means I need all files under all sub-directories under `c`. How to get that in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's consider an example.
Consider a directory containing the following files: 1.gif, 2.txt, card.gif and a subdirectory sub which contains only the file 3.txt.

Update:

[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) now offers an amazing interface for most common path operations. This task can also be done via pathlib as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r".") # path to the root dir from where you want to start searching

list(path.glob("**/*.txt"))
Out[1]: [WindowsPath('2.txt'), WindowsPath('sub/3.txt')]
```

For older answers see below

---

Using [glob.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

From Docs:

glob() will produce the following results. Notice how any leading components of the path are preserved.

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('./[0-9].*')
['./1.gif', './2.txt']
>>> glob.glob('*.gif')
['1.gif', 'card.gif']
>>> glob.glob('?.gif')
['1.gif']
>>> glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True) #python 3.5+
['2.txt', 'sub/3.txt']
>>> glob.glob('./**/', recursive=True)
['./', './sub/']
```

For python < 3.5

For older Python versions, use os.walk to recursively walk a directory and fnmatch.filter to match against a simple expression:

```
import fnmatch
import os

matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('src'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Comment: Two things not working. 1) `recursive` is not an argument. 2) If I do `./**/*` it will go down only single sub-directory, whereas I need all sub-directories (multi-level) to traverse.

Comment: hmm. what python version are you on? the docs i linked state python 3.5+ @AnirbanNag'tintinmj'

Comment: you should upgrade if you can. otherwise you might want to make a custom function that does the job for you, but that sounds annoying. @AnirbanNag'tintinmj'

Comment: try the edit solution, and see if that works for you @AnirbanNag'tintinmj'

Comment: Try adding recursive=True to the glob. So try list(path.glob("**/*.txt"), recursive=True):

Comment: Is this expression OS agnostic? Does `'*/*.csv'` work the same in Linux, so we don't have to rely on `os.path.join` for being os-agnostic?

Comment: Yep, should be. linux already uses forward slashes, (windows being the odd one out with using backslashes) and pathlib is handling os specific differences for us as necessary.